# Implementing AuthGuard on login page

Tags: angular, angular-router-guards

I am router guard so if the user has logged in, then it shouldn't allow users to go on `/login`. But I am able to go `/login` even tho I am logged in.

This is authGuard

```
export class AuthGuard implements CanActivate {
    constructor(private apiService: ApiService,
                private router: Router) {
    }

    canActivate(
        route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
        router: RouterStateSnapshot):
        | boolean
        | UrlTree
        | Promise<boolean | UrlTree>
        | Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
        return this.apiService.session.pipe(
            take(1),
            map(session => {
                const isAuth = !!session;
            if (isAuth) {
                    return true;
                }
                return this.router.createUrlTree(['/login']);

            })
        );
    }
}
```

Routing module

```
const routes: Routes = [
    {
        path: 'login',
        component: LoginComponent,
    },
    {
        path: 'dashboard',
        canActivate: [AuthGuard],
        component: DashboardComponent
    }
];
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build a guard for `login` route (basically similiar to your `AuthGuard`, but with an inverted logic):

```js
@Inject({providedIn: 'root'})
export class AuthLoginGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private apiService: ApiService, private router: Router) {}

  canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
      router: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> {
    return this.apiService.session.pipe(
      take(1),
      map(session => session ? this.router.createUrlTree(['/dashboard']) : true)
    );
  }
}
```

And add it to your login route:

```js
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'login',
    component: LoginComponent,
    canActivate: [AuthLoginGuard]
  },
  {
    path: 'dashboard',
    canActivate: [AuthGuard],
    component: DashboardComponent
  }
];
```

Comment: can I do something like [!AuthGuard]?

Comment: Nope. But if you opt to use functional guards instead of class based guards, you can almost do that.

Comment: Something like: `canActivate: [(route,state) => !yourGuard(route,state)`